# Redirect "/" to resourceful routes in Rails' routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

UPDATE (2018-Jan-11)

Based on suggestions, my files now look like the following. Behaviour remains the same (not working).

`/rottenpotatoes/app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def index
      redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

`/rottenpotatoes/config/routes.rb`:

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do

  # map '/' to be a redirect to '/movies'
  root 'movies#index'
  resources :movies
end
```

---

I am trying to redirect the default/home directory on an app to "movies#show". I can't seem to manage it -- 'URL/movies' works fine, but according to the server logs, a request for `/` displays 'assets/rails.png' (the "welcome to Rails" page).

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, I just don't know what it is. I have looked around SO and the Rails docs to no avail. I'm using c9.io, and running the server with `rerun -- rails s -p $PORT -b $IP`.

Rottenpotatoes/config/routes.rb:

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do

  # map '/' to be a redirect to '/movies'
  get "/", to: "movies#index" # I also tried movies#show
  resources :movies
end
```

`rake routes` says:

```
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy.
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: upgrade to 2.3.1.
RubyDep: WARNING: (To disable warnings, see:http://github.com/e2/ruby_dep/wiki/Disabling-warnings )
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
           GET    /                          movies#index
    movies GET    /movies(.:format)          movies#index
           POST   /movies(.:format)          movies#create
 new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)      movies#new
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) movies#edit
     movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#show
           PATCH  /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#update
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#update
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#destroy
```

How to I get "/" to go to "/movies"?

Comment: root to: 'movies#index' < Is that what you want?

Comment: Wow, should have just written it as an answer to get SO points haha

Comment: @kuwantum that is the point of the answers

Comment: I know but I was not 100% sure of what you wanted when I wrote it (not English native).

Comment: Try removing that index method, shouldn't be needed (I have never seen/used an index in the application controller anyway) and may be the cause of your issue. If it SHOULD be there, use `redirect_to root_path` not url

Comment: @kuwantum still no. I have no idea why `assets/rails.png` is being rendered when it hits `/`

Comment: That is so strange then - did you restart the rails server after making a routing changes? I'll keep thinking about it and get back to you if anything else springs to mind, but I don't see anything else which should be causing your problem to appear.

Comment: @kuwantum ya, I have restarted. I am wondering if it's something to do with c9.io (which I'm using for the project) and the outdated version of Ruby I have to use for the project.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to `movies/index` your default home page the try to the following in `routes.rb`

```
root 'movies#index'
```

The `/` is your root path if you use `<a href="/"> Home </a>` you will be redirected the home path

With the app method, you can access URL and path helpers, as well as do requests.

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.6)
irb(main):001:0> app.root_path
=> "/"
irb(main):002:0> app.get _
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-11 12:24:38 ....
```

Hope to help

Answer (score 2):

Please try

`root 'movies#index'`

Write it at the end of your routes.rb.

In routes.rb

`root` is used to define your root URL

And If its present more than once then it will be overridden by the last one.

Now after declaring `root movies#index`

You can use `redirect_to root_url` to redirect to `/movies` anywhere from your controllers

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `root WHATEVER` in `routes.rb` basically just defines the root directory in your app? Or does it define the resource reached at `/` (you could argue there is a subtle distinction here, as the true root directory wouldn't have anything above it in the directory tree).

Answer (score 0):

in routes.rb

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do

  # map '/' to be a redirect to '/movies'
  root 'movies#index'
  resources :movies, except: [:index]
end
```

and in controller where you want to redirect it

```
redirect root_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this according to your code, this works:

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do

  get "/", to: "movies#index", :as => "root" 
  resources :movies
end
```